# How to create code review request with Team Explorer Everywhere?

Tags: java, eclipse, tfs, eclipse-plugin, team-explorer-everywhere

We can create code review request from Visual Studio. Behind the scenes it creates a shelve set & code review request work item. Reviewer can review the code changes which further creates a TFS work item (code review response). Everything is captured in the TFS.

I could not find the same option in the TEE plug-in. Can anybody tell how can I achieve the same workflow? I do not want to manually create the shelve set & work item. Is there any plug-in available to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently TEE does **not support** code reviews, still on the backlog.

> I can't give you an exact (or, frankly, even an approximate) date.
>   There is a long list of priorities - code review support in TEE being
>   one of them. In April, we will start planning for our next update and
>   will see where this lands.
>
> Believe me, we like this feature (and could use it ourselves).
>
> Any other opinions/thoughts from the community are also useful to have
>   --- so, feel free to respond on this thread or reach out to me directly (wismythe AT microsoft.com).
>
> **Will Smythe**
>
> **Program Manager, Team Explorer Everywhere**

More detail info you can take a look at this similar question in MSDN: [Code Review functionality in TFS plugin for Eclipse](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/842f85cd-1dce-42ba-86db-7d21fadf874d/code-review-functionality-in-tfs-plugin-for-eclipse?forum=tee)